# How to identify a user on a Go server without constantly passing username/password

Tags: go, server

I am still new to webserver stuff, learning as i go (pardon the pun). But am a bit confused how to maintain identities of users making HTTP requests without asking for the username and password every time.

My client side is actually in C# (its a computer game) and my server will recieve http requests from the application. I could send the user id after login but any one could send user id and pretend to be some one they are not so isn't this a secuity issue?

I don't particularly want to be sending user/pass all the time since that will force me to HTTPS all the time due to sensitive information.

What is the general solution for this? I presume cookies can't be done since its C# application and not a browser like Chrome etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I presume cookies can't be done since its C# application and not a browser like Chrome etc.

Cookies are just a header called `Cookie` and aren't an issue for any reasonable HTTP library.

> I don't particularly want to be sending user/pass all the time since that will force me to HTTPS all the time due to sensitive information.

This is what Facebook, Twitter, and most other websites did 10 years ago. Secure login pages prevent your credentials from being stolen, but the other insecure endpoints you hit reveal whatever other information you use to authenticate. This allows your users to be impersonated by anybody monitoring your insecure connections. See [Firesheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep).

Since you should be securely storing your user's passwords, I would imagine verifying your user's password for every single request is slow.

If an account is guaranteed to never be used by more than one client at a time, you can just generate a random API token for each user, independent of their username and password. Otherwise, you will have to generate random session tokens when the user logs in and map them to the actual user with some sort of database. This is how most websites handle logins.

Regardless of what you do, there will be no way to prevent someone from impersonating another account if they know their secrets (username+password or session ID). This is why you have to use HTTPS and not just HTTP.

Comment: So all requests/responses should use HTTPS even if the data is non sensitive but requires the user to send a token of identity?

Comment: @Sir: Yes. The token is still sensitive. Less so than a username and password (which is probably reused on other websites/applications), but still sensitive, since it's what you use to authenticate your user.

Comment: Okay thanks :) I might aswell ditch HTTP as this point then !

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical approach for this is to use the session id:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID

Comment: What stops some one sending that session id in their json pretending to be a different player? How can the server know the difference?

Comment: @Sir server cannot. For that reason the session_id must be long and generated using a secure PRNG.

Comment: @Sir There 2 options. You store that long `Sessio_ID` on you server and try to find, if it's not found  - it's invalid. Or use JSON Web Tokens https://jwt.io/ - this way it's signed with you key.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass username and password every time on every request done by client. There are ways to do so.

1. You can use cookies to do so. For this you can make cookies whenever a Success login happen in your server and pass them to your client. The data will be kept with client and then your server will read cookies.

   But In your case you cannot use cookies as you are using C# for client. Hence you need to use other way listed below
2. You can use sessions Authentication Management. Sessions are the best way to make any login secure and reliable. For this you have to generate a session key which will be used then for verification of authenticated user. This will work as whenever a client login then a new session will be generated and in this way you can block other session created.

Below is the Code You can refer:

1. Login Function

   ```
   func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       sess := globalSessions.SessionStart(w, r)
       r.ParseForm()
       if r.Method == "GET" {
           t, _ := template.ParseFiles("login.gtpl")
           w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
           t.Execute(w, sess.Get("username"))
       } else {
           sess.Set("username", r.Form["username"])
           http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create Session

   ```
   func (manager *Manager) SessionStart(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (session Session) {
       manager.lock.Lock()
       defer manager.lock.Unlock()
       cookie, err := r.Cookie(manager.cookieName)
       if err != nil || cookie.Value == "" {
           sid := manager.sessionId()
           session, _ = manager.provider.SessionInit(sid)
           cookie := http.Cookie{Name: manager.cookieName, Value: url.QueryEscape(sid), Path: "/", HttpOnly: true, MaxAge: int(manager.maxlifetime)}
           http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
       } else {
           sid, _ := url.QueryUnescape(cookie.Value)
           session, _ = manager.provider.SessionRead(sid)
       }
       return
   }
   func (manager *Manager) sessionId() string {
       b := make([]byte, 32)
       if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, b); err != nil {
           return ""
       }
       return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
   }
   ```
3. Delete Session

   ```
   func init() {
       go globalSessions.GC()
   }

   func (manager *Manager) GC() {
       manager.lock.Lock()
       defer manager.lock.Unlock()
       manager.provider.SessionGC(manager.maxlifetime)
       time.AfterFunc(time.Duration(manager.maxlifetime), func() { manager.GC() })
   }
   ```

***Reference*** : https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/06.2.html